# Creating a tooltip from a system-tray only app

Tags: c#, tooltip, system-tray

So I'm trying to create a tooltip at some point on the screen.

```
ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
tip.Show("foobar", **IWin32Window window**, new Point(100, 100))
```

The problem is I don't know what to insert as the `window` parameter in the above. My app runs entirely out of the system tray, and has no other GUI elements. It's called `notifyIcon1`. That is created through `Form1`. Neither of these values work when plugged in to tip.Show().

How can I generate a tooltip anywhere on my screen using only the system tray?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want the tip to float above the tray, then you need to use the tray's window handle.

Comment: I want the tooltip to go wherever I want it to go via the Point parameter. So I don't care how it's being called or what form it's linked to, etc. I just want it to work. What do you mean by 'tray's window handle?'

Comment: Actually I see now that you have a form, is that correct? a form is a window so you should use your form.  Maybe you should post some code.

Comment: Did my answer get you what you need?

Comment: Thanks, reviewing it now but it looks good!

Answer (score 2):

The IWin32Window interface is a simple interface that only provides a `IntPtr` property named `Handle`. Feasibly something like this should work:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SO_ToolTip
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowWrapper windowWrapper = new WindowWrapper(GetDesktopWindow());
            ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
            toolTip.Show("Blah blah... Blah blah... Blah blah...", windowWrapper, 1, 1, 10000);
        }
    }

    public class WindowWrapper : IWin32Window
    {
        public WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
        {
            Handle = handle;
        }

        public IntPtr Handle { get; protected set; }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't. It complains about a NullReferenceException and I haven't debugged further. This does work:

```
...
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
    toolTip.Show("Blah blah... Blah blah... Blah blah...", this, 1, 1, 10000);
}
...
```

Although the position is relative to the current form. Maybe that will get you going in the right direction.

**Edit:** Even this doesn't work so I'm not sure if it's an issue with WindowWrapper (how?) or what:

```
...
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowWrapper windowWrapper = new WindowWrapper(this.Handle);
    ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
    toolTip.Show("Blah blah... Blah blah... Blah blah...", windowWrapper, 1, 1, 10000);
}
...
```

---

**Here you go,** use a transparent, maximized form that you `BringToFront()` before showing the `ToolTip`

**Form1 Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SO_ToolTip
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random _Random = new Random();
        ToolTip _ToolTip = new ToolTip();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BringToFront();
            _ToolTip.Show("Blah blah... Blah blah... Blah blah...", this, _Random.Next(0, Width), _Random.Next(0, Height), 10000);
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1 Designer Code:** So you can see the forms properties:

```
namespace SO_ToolTip
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // timer1
            // 
            this.timer1.Enabled = true;
            this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
            this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 264);
            this.ControlBox = false;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Opacity = 0;
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's that complicated, I vaguely remember that you can get an IWin32Window from a form without implementing your own class.

Comment: Correct, `Form` implements the `IWin32Window` interface, that's what happens when I pass `this` which is my Form1 object. The issue is that he wants to draw a tooltip anywhere on the screen (ie: to the desktop). Which by nature is just another window. I went the p/invoke route because I readily had a method to get the desktop handle.

Comment: Actually, this isn't quite correct. `BringToFront()` is bringing the the tooltip to the front, sure, but also taking the textbox I'm writing to out of focus. Not ideal.

Comment: This just seems so much harder than it should be. I did a prototype of this program in autohotkey. AHK has a `tooltip("foo", 10, 10)` method that put the tooltip wherever you wanted it. It's kinda insane that it isn't that easy with the much more robust C#.

Comment: the `NullReferenceException` is raised because that `System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.IsWindowActive(..)` is trying to cast IWin32Window into `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and check the next statement `windowControl.ShowParams & 0xF) != NativeMethods.SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE`. you can see it [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolTip@cs/1600728/ToolTip@cs)

Answer (score 1):

Joining late to the party:

In case you prefer/need to have WPF window:

```
    private class ToolTipWPFWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly TextBlock m_txtToDisplay = new TextBlock();
        private readonly DispatcherTimer m_timer = new DispatcherTimer();

        public ToolTipWindow(string p_strStringToDisplay, int p_intXOnScreen = 0, int p_intYOnScreen = 0, double p_dblDurationInMilliSeconds = 1500)
        {
            if (p_intXOnScreen == 0 && p_intYOnScreen == 0)
            {
                p_intXOnScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X;
                p_intYOnScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y;
            }

            m_txtToDisplay.Text = p_strStringToDisplay;
            m_txtToDisplay.Margin = new Thickness(3);

            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGoldenrodYellow);

            ShowInTaskbar = false;
            ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
            Topmost = true;

            // Location on screen - As Set
            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
            Left = p_intXOnScreen;
            Top = p_intYOnScreen;

            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;

            Content = m_txtToDisplay;
            m_timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(p_dblDurationInMilliSeconds);
            m_timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            m_timer.Start();
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (m_timer != null)
            {
                m_timer.Stop();
                m_timer.Tick -= timer_Tick;
            }

            Close();
        }
```

Usage:

```
// Display the ToolTip Window to the right of the Cursor
int intX = Cursor.Position.X + 20;
int intY = Cursor.Position.Y;

ToolTipWindow wpfWindow = new ToolTipWindow("Text To Display", intX, intY, 800);
wpfWindow.Show();
```

Result:

[image: wpf tooltip contains "Text To Display"]

I didn't implement the Mouse leave event, since I've used short display duration.